# How I create table View of webform submissions

Tags: views, 6, webforms

I want to view webform submissions in table view. I created a view of webform submissions but it shows a link for the data submitted. I dont want to use link, I want only simple table view.

Comment: You may be looking for this feature: http://drupal.org/node/680386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own tables of Webform submissions with Views...

1. Make a new view of type 'Webform submissions'
2. Add a page, set the path and set the Style to 'Table'.
3. Add the fields you want, sort and filter as needed.

If you want submissions filtered by the node (Webform) they were submitted against,  you should add a relationship for 'Webform submissions: Node' so you can pass the Node ID to the view -- remember to include the argument placeholder in your path for the nid (e.g. `submissions/%`)

*(Of course, this provides a tabular view of Webform submissions with the fields you choose as outlined in your question -- the existing view of submissions will still be on the tab for that Webform node... Changing that is a different question.)*

Comment: sorry for very very late reply. I made some changes with help of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In default webform results are arranged in Table format.If you wish to show webform results to users then just enable permissions in people>permission.